# Newlines in HTML elements? Will this break anything?

Tags: php, html

To avoid an exceedingly long line of code, I've decided to break it up according to the attributes in the HTML tag like so

```
            <tr class="<?php echo $in_cart?'in-cart':'' ?> ss-product-option" 
                data-in-cart="<?php echo $in_cart ?>" 
                data-product-option="<?php echo $o->option_id ?>" 
                id="ss-option-<?php echo $o->option_id ?>">
             ...
            </tr>
```

My question is this: Will this result in an incompatibility anywhere? Is this bad practice? I find this to be a bit cleaner and less confusing than if I had decided to newline within the  php tags.

Comment: No problem, you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no problem, you can make how many line breaks you want inside of an html tag.
This will not lead to any incompatibilities because, the html parsers typically discard the '\n' inside of html tags and process only the necessary.